# Plain old sql query for insert in codeigniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I've looked all over their docks but they really like to use active records. Can someone please tell me how to do a plain old SQL insert for an `INSERT` in `Codeigniter`?

EDIT

And this is for their `$this->db` object;

Comment: Why not using active record ?

Comment: Because active records don't do what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using query:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO ...");
```

Using active record:

```
$data = array(
 "attribute" => "value"
);
$this->db->insert("table_name", $data);
```

References:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to escape your inputs.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `yourtable` VALUES `foo`= ? WHERE `id` = ?";
return $this->db->query($sql, [$bar, $id]);
```

or for an update

```
$sql = "UPDATE `yourtable` SET `foo`= ?, `bar` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
return $this->db->query($sql, [$f, $b, $id]);
```